# MvvmCross on Xamarin.Mac

Tags: macos, xamarin, mvvmcross, xamarin.mac

Actually I'm trying to do something like described in this post [MvvmCross for WPF and Xamarin.Mac: is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24949833/mvvmcross-for-wpf-and-xamarin-mac-is-it-possible)

I'm new to mvvmcross and I'm trying to add it to my Xamarin.Mac Unified project. I can't do it through nuget and have a problem with adding needed references. Could someone provide a sample "hello world" xamarin.mac project with mvvmcross?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today, the state of the mac support in MvvmCross remains the same as before - as in [MvvmCross for WPF and Xamarin.Mac: is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24949833/mvvmcross-for-wpf-and-xamarin-mac-is-it-possible)

Yes, a few developers do successfully use it in MonoMac/Xamarin.Mac - but the project itself builds and releases binaries from Windows where there is no official support today for MonoMac or Xamarin.Mac.

For nuget, one developer has produced their own nuget packages for mac, but these are hard to use and maintain - as the Mac targets currently appear the same to nuget as the other x86 targets (WPF, console) - for some more on this see https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/502 (plus search other discussions there for "Mac" comments).

There is no official "Hello World" sample from MvvmCross for Mac - Mac is not as "first class" as the other platforms. There are some experiments included in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/3.5/Samples/FirstDemo.Mac

Comment: Thank you very much Stuart for your answer! I'm trying to use https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/3.5/Samples/FirstDemo.Mac. Where can I get all necessary binaries for this project to link them manually?

Comment: Ok, I've built the project, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Just coming back to Mvvmcross and Mac Stuart, looks like not much has changed since I dabbled with it.. is that right?